# Creating figure with all QTL mapping results in R

Tags: r, figure

I'm trying to create the figure below from my GWAS (Genome wide association) results of all the QTLs (Quantitative trait loci) I have identified. This figure has shown up in several papers I have read but no package is ever cited to help with making it and I'm hoping someone here can help.

[image]

The image breakdown is as follows. On the X-axis is the chromosome information. This is broken up into chromosomes (1A, 1B, ...) and then each QTLs base pair position on those chromosomes. The Y-axis is displaying metabolic classes but for other papers it would be traits where QTLs are measured. Each colored point is a QTL identified in the study. These figures are very helpful in finding genetic hotspots that can be hard to visualize from data tables.

Here is an example data table. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFdFd.png) There are normally around 70 to 100 QTLs that would be included and the example figure attached has around 300 since it is looking at metabolites. Traits were an included column but aren't necessary for this figure.

I'm fairly proficient with R so suggestions on packages for a starting point would be a huge help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we would need to see at least some test data and (to reduce the risk of closure for lack of focus or effort), at least a rudimentary attempt to reproduce the figure.  It would also be helpful, for those less familar with the subject area than you, to define some of the terms and acronyms you use: GWAS (genome wide associate study perhaps?) and QTL for example.